# how to compile and run speex codec on ios

Tags: ios, arm, cross-compiling

I want to create libspeex library for my ios app, I create the library using ./configure, make and make install commands, but when I add this library to Xcode I am getting some error like Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:

Comment: Did you cross compile? Sounds like you compiled it for your development machine.

Comment: In terminal I have only  given ./configure, make and make install commands,am I missing something. Could you please tell me how to cross compile.

Comment: Yeah, you're not cross compiling. I can't tell you exactly how to do it because I've never cross compiled anything with the iOS SDK. Usually, you'd have a cross compiler (which I assume will be included with the SDK) and you'd tell `./configure` to cross compile usually with a `--target=arch-target-triplet`. If you search for `cross compile libraries ios` on Google, you'll probably find helpful references.

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing errors related to SSE, you need to disable SSE by preventing `_USE_SSE` from being defined:

```
/* Enable SSE support */
/* #define _USE_SSE */
```

circa line 152 in `config.h`. This is the single-most common problem with compiling libspeex for iOS. Post additional error messages if this is not what you're encountering.